# How to fix my React Table cell problem (using React Table and MUI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-table

I am new to React and I created table component using React Table-MUI. Then I try to put my table row in to `<Box></Box>` like below code. Then I saw my whole table body is only take space of y first column and other columns are empty.

How do I correct this problem? The `<Box></Box>` is mandatory to wrap every row.

```
<TableContainer>
    <TableHeader>
    .
    .
    .
    </TableHeader>

    <TableBody>
        {data.map((item,index) => {
            return(
                <Box>
                   <TableCell></TableCell>
                   <TableCell></TableCell>
                   <TableCell></TableCell>
                </Box>
            )
        })}
    </TableBody>
</TableContainer>
```

I need to get every column under to it header. Right now whole row is in under first column. How can I do this?

Comment: You need `TableRow` and not `Box`. If you need box also put it *inside* the `TableRow`

Comment: I put that in table row and after that I wrap my table cells with Box. but the whole cells are still take only one column space.

Comment: Sorry, what I should of said is put the box inside of `TableCell`. You can't have it anywhere else, its invalid HTML otherwise. You also still need the tablerow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at table syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

And MUI table docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Under hood MUI table simple table with styles. You should not use div in tbody. Wrap cells with TableRow.